# Automapper can not use multiple configuration files but only one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have to projects **A** and **B**. They both have Automapper added to them. **B** references **A**. Each of them has Automapper configured as follows:

B:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfile());
            });
        }
    }

    public class UserProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<UserDto, UserVm>();
            CreateMap<NewUserVm, NewUserDto>();
        }
    }
```

A:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfile());
            });
        }
    }

    public class UserProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
            //CreateMap<NewUserVm, NewUserDto>();
        }
    }
```

I start the project and **B** makes a call to **A**. It goes to **A**, returns and when trying to make a mapping on B itself it says that there's no mapping configured for "CreateMap < UserDto, UserVm > ();". If I remove the config from **A** and don't use it, my mapper on **B** works as expected. This makes me think we are only using one instance somehow. Can you help me have two different instances on both projects?

Comment: Could you confirm that there is only one `UserDto` class which belongs to **A** project, and it's the same used in **B**? Also, what do you mean by *"If I remove the config from A..."*? You just remove the `Mapper.Initialize()` method? Or you just remove the `CreateMap<User, UserDto>();`?

Comment: Yes, it is only one UserDto used in both A and B. By removing I mean not using the Initialize method at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Mapper.Initialize()` twice in your application, one time per project, therefore one overrides another, that's why it works when you comment the `Mapper.Initialize()` in project **A** it works, because it stops overriding **B's** configurations.

One option to solve this, is making **B** calling **A's** `Configure`, and injecting its profiles like this:

---

### Reconfigure A to allow custom configurations to be passed

```
public class AutoMapperConfigForProjectA
{
    public static void Configure(Action<IMapperConfiguration> configuration = null)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfile());
            // if any callback config is passed, call it...
            if (configurations != null)
                configuration(cfg);
        });
    }
}

public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
        //CreateMap<NewUserVm, NewUserDto>();
    }
}
```

I just renamed `AutoMapperConfig` to `AutoMapperConfigForProjectA` in **project A**.

---

### Call `AutoMapperConfigForProjectA.Configure()` in project B, adding its own configs

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapperConfigForProjectA.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfileForB());
        });
    }
}

public class UserProfileForB : Profile
{
    public UserProfileForB()
    {
        CreateMap<UserDto, UserVm>();
        CreateMap<NewUserVm, NewUserDto>();
    }
}
```

I also renamed `UserProfile` to `UserProfileForB` in project B, because I'm not sure if having profiles with the same name cause any troubles.